# jQuery selector to find the last element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I will really appreciate if someone can tell me how this might be possible.

If I have the following html,

```
<span><hr class=​"tierEnd">​</span>
<span><hr class=​"tierEnd">​</span>
<span><hr class=​"tierEnd">​</span>
<span><hr class=​"tierEnd">​</span>
```

How can I select the last **hr** element?

Tried with `last-child,` `last`, `last-of-type` already

Comment: `hr:last` works for me : http://jsfiddle.net/hEYz6/

Comment: Are you sure you tried all of them like you said?

Comment: You should show what you tried so people can explain what was wrong.

Comment: If your spans happen to be in a container you could do: `$('.container span:last-child hr')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **[`:last`](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/)** or **[`.last()`](http://api.jquery.com/last/)**

```
$('hr:last')
```

or

```
$('hr').last()
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hEYz6/)**

---

`last-child` and `last-of-type` does not work in  case of `<hr>`

In that case use `$('span:last-of-type hr')`

Comment: Thanks, thought $('span:last-of-type hr') didn't work. but $('hr:last') did. Not sure why my question has a -1 :(

Answer (score 4):

Use jquery `:last` selector

```
$(".tierEnd:last")
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use the `.last()` jQuery method:

```
$(".tierEnd").last()
```

For some reason, it is thought to be faster than the pseudo selector.

Comment: *"For some reason, it is thought to be faster than the pseudo selector."* That's because when using pseudo selector, jQuery has to evaluate a string first (which is made by calling some function) and then call the function `.last()`. The string interpretation a the additional calls make it slower than directly calling the function.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery("span > .tierEnd").last()
```

or

```
jQuery("span > .tierEnd:last")
```

Using `span > .tierEnd` will only select direct descendants of a span tag with `tierEnd` class

Answer (score 0):

You should use the below selector to get the last `<hr>` element.

**`jQuery("span:last-child hr.tierEnd")`**

Please like if this helps you! Cheers :)